# Can Arduino be used as an FDTI Programmer?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I would like to program my ESP 8266 WiFi module. But I don't have an FDTI right now is there any way to use Arduino Uno as FDTI Programmer then use ESP without it.

Comment: This would be answered better on arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can use this guide on instructables to get you started. http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Examples-2-Use-an-Arduino-as-a-FTDI-Progr/